# C++ pointers to class and destructing class

Tags: c++, pointers

Having a class that is created throw a `new` keyword and a pointer pointing to it , then calling a method from the class to destroy the class it self, should i have to free the memory from the pointer or not? somthing like that:

.h

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
    void destroy();
    bool operator==(Test& right){return id == right.id;};
private:
    static int count;
    std::list<Test*>::size_type id;
    static std::list<Test*> instances;
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"
int Test::count = 0;
std::list<Test*> Test::instances;
Test::Test()
{
    instances.push_back(this);
    id = count++;

}
Test::~Test()
{
}

void Test::destroy()
{
    for(auto t : instances){
        if(*t == *this)
        {
            delete t;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

source

```
Test* n = new Test();
n->destroy();
```

so my question is the memory pointed to by n is freed up? or should i call `delete n`

Comment: Why in the range-for loop do you only want to delete elements that is the current element pointed to by `this`? Aren't you leaking memory in that case?

Comment: yeah, in destroy, just have **delete this;**, but it looks like you can just do **delete n;** to save all the trouble.  One reason to use something like *delete this;* is if you want to decrease the reference count in destroy(.) and delete only if it's 0.

Comment: why does it leak memory?!

Comment: you're *leaking* memory as it is because you never remove stuff from **instances**.

Comment: so i should use instance.erase() then i call delete this?

Comment: get rid of **instances** altogether.  in place of n->destroy(), just use delete n; unless there is a reason to use n->destroy().  if there is a reason, what is it?  and in that case, inside Test::Destroy, just have delete this;

Comment: suppose i created a window with `new` and I have `instances` as a container for any window created , then that window recieve a destroy event, the window will call its destroy method, and clear the container , at such time i dont have the pointer pointing to the memory created so i cant just call `delete` on it

Comment: alternatively, you can just **delete** that object in the destroy event WM_DESTROY (instead of calling destroy).  if you don't have a pointer to the object, then you also can't call destroy?

Comment: Indeed that pointer is comming from the `instance` container it should be a `map<HWND,CLASS*>` so on `WM_DESTROY` i would call `instance[hwnd]->destory` then the `destory` method should do any custom stuff, handle removing its pointer fromm `instances` and then  freeing class memory by calling `delete` .So does it differ if those  things  are made in `WM_DESTROY` part or in a method?

Comment: you can do either when you get WM_DESTROY.  (1) call instance[hwnd]->destroy() and have the destroy function remove from map, clean up, then do delete this; or (2) delete instance[hwnd]; instance.erase(hwnd);  in this case, put your cleanup code into the destructor.   choice (2) may be more preferable in that you don't have to do **delete this;** which some people may find unattractive, although is technically ok.

Comment: I see , thanks for your help to clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is discussed in the comments in case somebody finds this later.

Basically, looks like you are trying to encapsulate Windows' windowing mechanism and want to destroy the window class on WM_DESTROY.

You've got a map that maps from HWND to the class:

```
        map<HWND,CLASS*> instances;
```

When WM_DESTROY is received, you can do one of two things:

**1.  destroy function option**

```
 instance[hwnd]->destroy();
```

Inside destroy, you would have something that looks like this:

```
void CLASS::destroy() {
     // assuming hwnd is a member (probably m_hwnd)
     instance.erase(hwnd);  
     // do some cleanup, and then delete the instance
     delete this;
}
```

**2.  delete option**

```
delete instance[hwnd];
instance.erase(hwnd);
```

in this case, you have to put all the clean up code into the destructor of the class.

Option 2 is probably more preferable since it doesn't require you to do **delete this;**, which while technically ok, may appear unattractive to some people.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but why do it this way? Why not just `delete n`?